az synapse role definition list failing with <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024CC2AA53D0>
When the code below is executed against a synapse analytics workspace,
az synapse role definition list --workspace-name workspace_name

I then get the error
<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024CC2AA53D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Any idea what could be causing the error ?

You can try the following steps:
You will need to have the Synapse Contributor or Synapse Admin role.
Step 1: Open the Synapse Workspace and navigate to Manage.

Step 2: Navigate to Access Control.

Step 3: In the workspace scope, assign Synapse roles.

az synapse role definition list --workspace-name dileepsynapse

Results:

Reference: az synapse role definition

the issue here is that when i go to access control, I can only see synapse administrator and it fails to assign the role to any user.
